# How to match the last space in this pattern and string?

Tags: python, regex, vim

```
s = "DL666 DL777 DL888 这波值不值你下载"
```

I want to match characters starting from the last space, so the match should be:

```
m = "这波值不值你下载"
```

I wrote this pattern, but it didn't work:

```
p = '\s.+?$'
```

I had thought the ? is for non-greedy search.

Comment: Split the string by space and take the last in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using regex for this, I'd just do a greedy search for "anything followed by whitespace" and then use a capture group to take everything after that.

```
import re

s = "DL666 DL777 DL888 这波值不值你下载"
m = re.match(r'^.*\s(.*)$', s).group(1)
# '这波值不值你下载'
```

An even more straightforward regex, if you're content with not starting at the beginning of the line, would be

```
m = re.search('[^\s]*$', s).group(0)
# '这波值不值你下载'
```

However, for something this simple, you might be better off just using `str.rindex()` to find the last occurrence of a space, and taking everything after it.:

```
m = s[s.rindex(' ') + 1:]
# '这波值不值你下载'
```

Comment: Green, this is python code. Is there  pattern that I can do directly in vim?

Comment: @marlon I'm not sure - I don't have much experience with vim - but [vim does support regex](http://vimregex.com/) and the expression `^.*\s(.*)$` should be compatible with it, being a simple and straightforward regex expression that doesn't use any platform-specific features.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work is because it tries to find a match from *left to right*.

The regex `\s.+?$` means:

- Match one whitespace `\s`
- Followed by any number `+?` of any character `.`
- Until you reach the end of the line (or string) `$`

The `$` after the `?` makes the `?` useless.

That's why it matches everything after the first space in your string.
 `DL777 DL888 这波值不值你下载`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X51ZMx/1)

On the other hand, if you changed the `.` to anything *except* whitespace (`\S`), you'd get what you want. While you're at it, you might as well remove the `?`. And since you don't care about the whitespace before the non-whitespace, get rid of the `\s` as well.
`\S+$` matches `这波值不值你下载` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2JWjuF/2)

Note that while this regex works, it's cheaper to just use `str.rindex()` and slice the string like [GCG suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67223754/843953) in their answer to this question.

Comment: This is great too!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler regex that you can also use as a search string in vim is:

```
\S\+$
```

It matches every non-whitespace until the end of line (or string if python). Note that you have to escape the `+` in vim.

Here is the python script:

```
import re
s = "DL666 DL777 DL888 这波值不值你下载"
m = re.search(r'\S+$', s)
print(m.group(0))
```

I tested it in python3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Mar  9 2021, 15:08:44) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> s = "DL666 DL777 DL888 这波值不值你下载"
>>> m = re.search(r'\S+$', s)
>>> print(m.group(0))
这波值不值你下载
>>>
```